# DOM not parsing correctly

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, parsing, dom

I have a script which loads items from an XML file, and displays them, so a user can choose which item they want to remove from their file. Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

$userid= $current_user->ID;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load("playlists/$userid.xml");

echo '<div class="styled-select">';
echo '<center><form name="input" action="/remove/removesure.php" method="get">';
echo '<select name="q[]" size="2" multiple>';

$titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
foreach ($titles as $title) {

    echo '<option>'.$title->nodeValue.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
echo '<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Remove">';
echo '</form></center>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

The problem I've ran into is that it doesn't display some objects correctly, mainly items with hyphens (it displays – instead of -) and titles with spaces at the end, and because of this, my removal code doesn't find the item, and so can't remove it. I don't know what to do, and I don't know why it's doing this. I'm running the code in wordpress, if that makes a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if it will fix your problem, but you should definitely be HTML-escaping the output. Try `echo '<option>'.html_entities($title->nodeValue).'</option>';`

Comment: "*I'm running the code in wordpress, if that makes a difference.*" — it makes a difference.

Comment: @salathe how so? I'm using a plugin that lets me run php in pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no chance of having any kind of councurrency, I would suggest you to use the title index of the title tag as value of "option". Eg:

```
$titles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
$counter = 0;
foreach ($titles as $title) {
    echo '<option value='.$counter.' >'.$title->nodeValue.'</option>';
    $counter++;
}
```

In removesure.php, you could handle this by using an XPath expression like the next one:

```
//Title[2]
```

where "2" is the index of the title that must be removed.

That is a possible solution; another path you could try to follow is to handle spaces providing the best encoding option for your titles. [htmlentity](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) is the function that you should execute

```
echo '<option>'.htmlentity($title->nodeValue).'</option>'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never even thought of doing that, and it makes much more sense than the way I used to do it. It works perfectly so far, still have to do a bit more testing, but looking good! Thanks for the help!